# how to specify classpath with java_language_server of neovim?

Tags: java, gradle, neovim, language-server-protocol, nvim-lspconfig

I setup and config a [java language server](https://github.com/georgewfraser/java-language-server) using ":Lsp install" and lspconfig plugin, but I cannot jump to classes in my project,

I just open single file and for every packages, java language server gives me "package ... does not exist".

my project is a gradle project and it contains some sub projects with same 'build.gradle'.

do I need to specify classpath project by project?

Can anyone teach me how to use it?